# mongoose | search by array of fields in array of populated items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is my schema:

Post:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   ...
   tags: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Tag"
   }]
   ...
})
```

Tag:

```
const tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
```

**Question**

is there a way to feed the Post model with an array of names of tags and find the posts that contains those tags?

Something like:

```
exports.getPostsByTags = (req, res, next) => {
    var tags = JSON.parse(req.params.tags);
    //HOW TO USE Post.find({.....}) So i can retrieve posts which contains var tags array
    Post.find({.....}).populate("tags")
        .then(documents => {
            fetchedPosts = documents;
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Posts by Tags fetched succesfully!",
                posts: fetchedPosts,
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Fetching posts by Tags failed"
            })
        });
}
```

example route call:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/posts/tags/[{"name": "d2"}, {"name": "d1"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions), you can pass a `match` object to the `populate` call, where you could do something like:

```
const tags = JSON.parse(req.params.tags).map(tag => tag.name);
Post.find({}).populate({
            path: 'tags',
            match: {
                name: {$in: tags}
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is working! the only problem is that it returns the posts with empty tags.

Comment: actually, it is not working, it returns all the posts but erases the tags that are not in the tags array

Comment: i got it working by iterating the result and checking if post.tags.length>0. If there is a more optimal way let me know :) thank you for your effort!